# 2 step authentication with django rest framework

Tags: django, reactjs, django-authentication, one-time-password, two-step-verification

## EDIT

i am looking to implement a 2 step authentication into my django application. Previously , i have used the package django-two-step-auth, however i have made the decision to adopt the django x react.js combination. Unfortunately there is not much documentations talking about using this package with DRF. Has anyone successfully implemented the package in their django x react application?
It would be great if someone could point me in the correct direction!

Thanks

Comment: [djangopackages.org](https://djangopackages.org/)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I apologise for previously asking an off-topic question , i have made some edits to keep the discussion more focused